# SharePoint Designer: Error when connecting to my customer production server

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer

Every time I try to connect to any SharePoint site running on my customer server I get the following error.

> An error occurred accessing your Microsoft SharePoint Foundation site
>   files. Authors - if authoring against a Web server, please contact the
>   Webmaster for this server's Web site. WebMasters - please see the
>   server's application event log for more details.

I already checked the sharepoint options in CA and in every site in the mentioned server. Everything seens correct but the error persists.

It looks like there is no direct relation to SharePoint and something else in the server but I was not able to determine what could cause such behaviour.

Hope someone here has something to say.

Comment: What version of Sharepoint? Are you connecting to On-premise instance? Did you check Control Permissions to SharePoint Designer? http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kaevans/archive/2011/07/11/test-permissions-grid.aspx  You can run ULS Viewer and stop just after error is raised - then review more detailed logs.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the reply.
It is a SharePoint 2013 with sp1 and CU installed. It is a on-premise instance and I have checked Event Viewer logs and ULS. I didn't found anything useful anywhere.

Comment: You can try fiddler - http://www.telerik.com/fiddler and watch what is being transfer while connecting to server using Sharepoint Designer - there will probably be returned some more indept errors. Communication between Sharepoint Designer and Sharepoint is all by web services - that's why this will be visible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well...  After a very long and painful headache we were able to find out what was causing this malfunction.

It was a .net agent from New Relic. This agent is used to analyse traffic, page load time and some other cool things. It basicly add some javascript to the head session of every response our IIS make and this code send some data to New Relic servers that will be processed to build some reports about the applications running in the IIS.

In the end, I just disabled it and SPD turned back to life.

Thanks.

Comment: Thank you! I had the same issue and I only thought it was a coincidence that the issue started around the same time that the New Relic .Net Agent was installed on our Sharepoint server. We've never had issues with the .Net Agent on any of our other .Net applications and we are happy with New Relic overall. 

I still have the New Relic Server Monitoring on the Sharepoint server but at some point, I would like to re-visit the issue at hand and see if I can get the .Net Agent up and running as well.